# What does the syntax $P(X=n)$ mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, notation

I'm reading a text book about probability and this syntax $P(X=n)$ keeps resurfacing. I've googled around, but I keep getting results on binomial distributions.

What does $P(X=n)$ mean? Does it mean that a certain value $X$ has a variance of $n$? Does it perchance have something to do with a concept called a "random variable"?

Comment: Let $X$ be a random variable. Then $P(X=n)$ is the *probability* that $X$ takes on the value $n$.

Comment: $X$ is a random variable, and $P(X=n)$ means the probability that $X$ takes the value $n$.

Comment: Oh thank you, so X is just some random value out there? Such as a coin flip?

Comment: Maybe you could tell us the name of the book that you are reading since it is seems to be unusual in using common notation without any explanation, and also unable to convey the concept of a random variable with any clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of a *random variable* $X$ as a function that maps events to real numbers, i.e., $X : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The expression $P(X=n)$ denotes the probability that a random variable $X$ has value $n$. Formally, it is a short form for the probability of the event $\{\omega : X(\omega)=n\}$, i.e., $$P(X=n) = P(\{\omega : X(\omega)=n\}).$$
This is also explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Distribution_functions_of_random_variables).

For example, if your events are the outcome of throwing a die, you would write the probability of getting a $3$ as $P(X=3)$.

Answer (score 1):

For example your $X$ could be the number of broken eggs in a packet of $6$. Then $X \in \{0, \dots, 6 \}$ and $P(X = 2) = {6 \choose 2} p^2 (1-p)^{6-2}$ where $p$ is the probability that an egg is broken.